# Syntax for declaring javascript array of ojbects with named properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to be able to reference a javascript array of objects by the names of the object properties

```
 var currentColour = phones[1].TextColour;
```

or even better

```
var currentColour = phones(Number == "7483427273").TextColour;
```

How do I declare the array?

What I've tried...

```
var phones = [ new Object(Number = '1234282248', DisplayBold = false),
new Object(Number = ... etc ];

var phones = [ [ new phone(Number = '1234282248', DisplayBold = false ... etc
```

(with various combinations of square and curly braces)

This is the nearest I can get, but is referenced by numbers only: (i.e. phones[1][3] )

```
 var phones = [
   [Number = '1234282248', DisplayBold = false, DisplayItalic = true, FillColour = '#FF4169E1', TextColour = '#FFFFFF00'],
   [Number = '7483427273', DisplayBold = true, DisplayItalic = false, FillColour = '#FFFF0000', TextColour = '#FFADFF2F'],
   [Number = '9465601196', DisplayBold = true, DisplayItalic = false, FillColour = '#FF191970', TextColour = '#FFF0FFFF']
 ];
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using an array with objects? I don't see why you would like what you have? In the end, you could then use `find` and `some` on the array to filter down to your number

Comment: I don't use javascript much - Can you expand on this?

Comment: Yeah, I put up an answer for you, I hope that helps a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where your confusion is coming from but you would better define your phone numbers as normal object like

```
var phones = [
   {Number: '1234282248', DisplayBold: false, DisplayItalic: true, FillColour: '#FF4169E1', TextColour: '#FFFFFF00'},
   {Number: '7483427273', DisplayBold: true, DisplayItalic: false, FillColour: '#FFFF0000', TextColour: '#FFADFF2F'},
   {Number: '9465601196', DisplayBold: true, DisplayItalic: false, FillColour: '#FF191970', TextColour: '#FFF0FFFF'}
 ];
```

and then you can find a phone number using the `Array.prototype.find` method, like:

```
let match = phones.find( p => p.Number === '7483427273' );
if ( !match) {
  // no match found
  return;
}
// here match would be the second phone number in the array
```

if you just want to find the index, you could use the `Array.prototype.findIndex` method, like:

```
let index = phones.findIndex( p => p.Number === '7483427273' );
if ( index === -1) {
  // no match found
  return;
}
// here index would be 1 as the second phone number in the array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const phones = [
{Number: '1234', DisplayBold: false, DisplayItalic: true, FillColour: '#etc'},
{Number: '1234', DisplayBold: false, DisplayItalic: true, FillColour: '#etc'},
{Number: '1234', DisplayBold: false, DisplayItalic: true, FillColour: '#etc'},
];
```

Then you access it by doing `phones[index].Number`

Answer (score 0):

First you'll need to use the correct [Object initialiser syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) to create an array of phones.

```
let phones = [{
    Number: '1234282248',
    DisplayBold: false,
    DisplayItalic: true,
    FillColour: '#FF4169E1',
    TextColour: '#FFFFFF00'
  }, ...
```

Then you can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find objects with required property values:

```js
let phones = [{
    Number: '1234282248',
    DisplayBold: false,
    DisplayItalic: true,
    FillColour: '#FF4169E1',
    TextColour: '#FFFFFF00'
  },
  {
    Number: '7483427273',
    DisplayBold: true,
    DisplayItalic: false,
    FillColour: '#FFFF0000',
    TextColour: '#FFADFF2F'
  },
  {
    Number: '9465601196',
    DisplayBold: true,
    DisplayItalic: false,
    FillColour: '#FF191970',
    TextColour: '#FFF0FFFF'
  }];

// get the first phone with the desired Number
let currentPhone = phones.find((phone) => phone.Number == "7483427273");
let currentColour = currentPhone.TextColour;

console.log('Current colour:', currentColour);
```